# How to escape "[" in Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm having a problem with escaping characters in Java. My code looks like this:

```
 String pattern = "^\\[set (\\d+) (\\d+) \\]$";
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            // Create a Pattern object
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

            // Now create matcher object.

            while (true) {
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
                if (m.find()) {
                    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
                    System.out.println("Set value: " + m.group(2));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
                }
            }
```

I want to search for the instruction like this:

> [set 6 7]

How to do this?

Comment: remove the anchors `^` and `$`, it isn't related to square brackets and the way to escape them.

Comment: not working when removed the anchors

Comment: You should also take out the last space as it won't match [set 6 7] (It will match [set 6 7 ]): "\\\[set (\\d+) (\\d+)\\\]"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working now

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure how many whitespaces there may be, use `\s+` to match 1+ whitespaces and `\s*` to match zero or more of them.

See a [sample demo](http://ideone.com/giAH09):

```
String rx = "\\[set\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s*]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = p.matcher("[set 6 7]");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tS3yX8/1)